# Is there a built-in method or gem that can print a Ruby array in columns?

Tags: ruby, pretty-print

I have a large Ruby array that I would like to print in columns, just like the default output of Unix' 'ls' command (on OS X, at least).  Is there a gem or built-in method that can do this?  I am aware of the awesome_print gem.  It's got some sexy output but it doesn't seem to offer columns.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to code this manually. It's 5 lines of code :)

Comment: How about posting some sample data and some sample output? My crystal ball is offline today.

Comment: @Sergio: The reason I ask this question here is not because I don't know how to code it manually, but rather because I'm looking for something in the standard library or a gem that I can require so that I can shorten my own code.

Comment: @CodeGnome: I'm not sure what you're looking for in the way of sample code.  This is a simple question about what's out there, I am not looking for a multi-line code solution.  I realize I should change the title to reflect this.  Sorry about your crystal ball, that happens to me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`hirb`](https://rubygems.org/gems/hirb) is more useful:

```
require 'hirb'

Hirb.enable :output=>{"Array"=>{:class=>Hirb::Helpers::Table}}  #=> true

[[1,2], [2,3]]
+---+---+
| 0 | 1 |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
+---+---+
2 rows in set

[[5,6,3,4]]
+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 5 | 6 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+
1 row in set
```

Comment: Awesome.  This is just about what I was looking for.  In your example, I see you have to feed it an array of arrays, so you would need to use Enumerable#each_slice first if you have just a 1D array.  This is a minor thing, but I am still wondering: can hirb autotable a 1D array?

Answer (score 7):

[Enumerable#each_slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) may be your friend.

```
$ irb
irb> a = (0..18).to_a
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
irb> a.each_slice(5) { |row| puts row.map{|e| "%5d" % e}.join("  ") }
    0      1      2      3      4
    5      6      7      8      9
   10     11     12     13     14
   15     16     17     18
```

If you want them ordered within columns, you can use slice and [Enumerable#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip)

```
irb> cols = a.each_slice((a.size+2)/3).to_a
=> [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]
irb> cols.first.zip( *cols[1..-1] ).each{|row| puts row.map{|e| e ? '%5d' % e : '     '}.join("  ") }
    0      7     14
    1      8     15
    2      9     16
    3     10     17
    4     11     18
    5     12       
    6     13
```

Comment: Very slick.  I will use this.  I am still wondering whether there is a standard library or common gem function somewhere that handles this though, perhaps adjusting column spacing automatically.

Comment: @Sean: very slick indeed, i like those answers which really teach you something, thanks dbenhur, but do you realize that when you include a gem you include perhaps thousand of lines of code ? why then bother with a few lines of code to do the job ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the commenters Sean but I just couldn't hold myself and instead held my pee to give birth to this cutie, I'm on Windows so don't know how the output of ls is alike but I'm sure there are options enough here to give you the desired output

```
cm = {'headers' => ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'], 'width' => [5, 5, 16, 30], 'separator' => '|', 'align' => [:left,:right,:left,:right]}
a = [["on", "two", "three", "a loooooooooooooooonger field"],["four","five","looooooooooonger","short one"]]
cm['headers'].each_with_index{|header, index|w = cm['width'][index];print "#{cm['align'][index]==:left ? header.ljust(w)[0..w-1]:header.rjust(w)[0..w-1]}#{cm['separator']}"}
puts ""
a.each do |record|
  record.each_with_index do |field, index|
    w = cm['width'][index]
    print "#{cm['align'][index]==:left ? field.ljust(w)[0..w-1]:field.rjust(w)[0..w-1]}#{cm['separator']}"
  end
  puts ""
end
```

gives

```
first|secon|third           |                        fourth|
on   |  two|three           | a loooooooooooooooonger field|
four | five|looooooooooonger|                     short one|
```

Comment: Ye gods that is a scary cutie.  I appreciate that it gets the job done but there are simpler solutions.

Comment: i go for full fledged and reusable, although i think it could be done shorter but that's beyond my current knowledge of Ruby

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my first full fledged configurable solution here a shorter one based on the maximum string length of the elements

```
class Array
  def to_table l = []
    self.each{|r|r.each_with_index{|f,i|l[i] = [l[i]||0, f.length].max}}
    self.each{|r|r.each_with_index{|f,i|print "#{f.ljust l[i]}|"};puts ""}
  end
end

[["on", "two", "three", "a loooooooooooooooonger field"],["four","five","looooooooooonger","short one"]].to_table
```

gives

```
on  |two |three           |a loooooooooooooooonger field|
four|five|looooooooooonger|short one                    |
```

Comment: This looks like a decent extension, and much cleaner than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Some improvements on @peter's solution:

1. Raise an exception if the caller is not an Array of arrays;
2. Type cast to string any value to it will work on arrays containing a mix of strings and numbers;
3. Any column separator string could be specified as argument;
4. The output is a String formatted as a table so it could be handled further and won't break anything if an output is not expected.

```rb
class Array

  # Convert an Array of arrays into a String, formatted as a table.
  def columnize(sep="  ")
    each{|r| r.is_a? Array or raise NoMethodError, "Must be called on an Array of arrays."}
    s = ""
    l = []
    each{|r|r.each_with_index{|f,i| l[i] = [l[i]||0, f.to_s.length].max}}
    each{|r|r.each_with_index{|f,i| s << "#{f.to_s.ljust l[i]}#{sep}"}; s << "\n"}
    return s
  end
 
 end
```

Called like

```
puts [["field", 2, 3, "another field"],[4,5,"looooooooooonger","short one"]].columnize(" | ")
```

produces this output

```
field | 2 | 3                | another field | 
4     | 5 | looooooooooonger | short one     |
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code from @Claudio Floreani, cleaned up a bit.

```rb
class Array
  # Convert an Array of Array into a String, formatted as a table.
  def columnize(separator = '  ')
    each { |row| row.is_a? Array or raise NoMethodError, 'Must be called on an Array of Array.' }
    result = ''
    l = []
    each { |row| row.each_with_index { |f, i| l[i] = [l[i] || 0, f.to_s.length].max } }
    each do |row|
      row.each_with_index { |f, i| result << "#{f.to_s.ljust l[i]}#{separator}" }
      result << "\n"
    end
    result
  end
end
```